# Is Samsung Tab S8 going to respond faster than Tab S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-s-3, samsung-galaxy-tab-s8

My wife is using Tab S3.  And finds it a bit slow to respond.  I am looking at the Tab S8 Ultra.  I know the CPU is more than twice as fast.  But does this translate to response speed ?

Comment: And the reason for the downvote is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. There's more RAM, a better CPU, and a newer operating system. It'll almost be like night and day.

[Click here](https://m.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?&idPhone2=5422&idPhone1=11343) for a specs a specs comparison between the two.

[Click here](https://www.androidauthority.com/qualcomm-snapdragon-8-gen-1-3063350/) for a review of the snap dragon 8 gen 1 inside tge Tab s8.

If you click [here for 8 gen1](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Qualcomm-Snapdragon-8-Gen-1-Processor-Benchmarks-and-Specs.633861.0.html), and [here for Marvell PXA986](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Marvell-PXA986-Processor.97659.0.html), you'll see that the Snapdragon 8gen1 in the galaxy tab s8 is over 1000 times faster than the Marvell PXA986 in the galaxy tab S3.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).